# My Toyota kills USB sticks connected to USB/AUX music port

Tags: electrical, toyota, audio, repair, corolla

I have a Corolla 2013 S. It's the second time happening. The USB stick was connected to the Audio USB/AUX port like always (#19 below). I was just trying to play some music, and realized it doesn't play and `USB` option is gone. And when I connect it to my computer, it doesn't even show the stick. Looks like my car is killing them somehow.

What's happening?

[image]

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the USB port is a feature of the vehicle's entertainment system (as it is in our 2013 Rav4EV) or is it merely a charge port?

Comment: A USB port for charging only might be labelled with the voltage &  amperage provided; e.g. 5V/1.0A, 5V/2.4A, etc. An AUX media port would not be labelled this way. However, there are USB charging only ports that are not labelled with current output; it's not a mandatory designation, only a good idea.

Comment: To clarify, are you referring to the USB/AUX port from page 3 of [this](https://www.toyota.com/t3Portal/document/om-s/OM13E1QRG/pdf/OM13E1QRG.pdf)?

Comment: Yes. #19 (USB/AUX).

Comment: Updated the question